# getting select from a nested query with multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

below is the given table.

```
----------------------------------
| area   |  country  |   date     |  
----------------------------------
| a1     |     c1    | 13-01-2013 | 
----------------------------------
| a2     |     c2    | 06-01-2013 | 
----------------------------------
| a3     |     c1    | 12-01-2013 | 
----------------------------------
| a4     |     c2    | 10-01-2013 | 
----------------------------------
| a5     |     c3    | 13-01-2013 | 
----------------------------------
| a1     |     c1    | 13-01-2013 | 
----------------------------------
| a2     |     c2    | 06-01-2013 | 
----------------------------------
| a3     |     c1    | 12-01-2013 | 
----------------------------------
| a4     |     c2    | 10-01-2013 | 
----------------------------------
| a5     |     c3    | 13-01-2013 |
```

I want my query to do to following.

"Show the name of the countries that have the area present more than once between 2 given dates."

I tried the below query but it is giving me an error. > 
 #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
SELECT country
FROM table
WHERE area = (
SELECT area
FROM table
WHERE dateandtime > ' 13-01-2013'
AND dateandtime < '20-01-2013'
GROUP BY area
HAVING count(DISTINCT date) > 1 );
```

Comment: Change your first `AND` to `WHERE` in your subquery, and see where that gets you.

Comment: done. however, the error still remains the same.

Comment: That was a quick response. You tested it to make sure it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

To compare a value to a list of values, you need to use `IN`. I also made a couple changes to fix your syntax.

```
SELECT country
FROM table
WHERE area IN (
SELECT area
FROM table
WHERE dateandtime > ' 13-01-2013'
AND dateandtime < '20-01-2013'
GROUP BY area, country, `date`
HAVING count(date) > 1 )
);
```

I believe the query could also be simplified to:

```
SELECT country
FROM table
GROUP BY area, country, `date`
HAVING count(date) > 1
AND dateandtime BETWEEN '14-01-2013' AND '19-01-2013'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a country, don't select an area:

```
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM (
   SELECT country
   FROM table
   WHERE dateandtime > ' 13-01-2013'
   AND dateandtime < '20-01-2013'
   GROUP BY area
   HAVING count(DISTINCT date) > 1
) areas;
```

Answer (score 0):

you may looking for this

```
    SELECT country
    FROM table1

    WHERE date between ' 13-01-2013' AND  '20-01-2013'

    GROUP BY country
    HAVING count(date) > 1 ;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa1c1)